# Django Models and Admin Inlines

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to have a set of questions with individual answers, that each user can answer.
To achieve this kind of function, I built the following models:

models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question = models.TextField(null=False)

class PossibleAnswer(models.Model):
  question=models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="possible_answer")
  answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  real_answer = models.ForeignKey(PossibleAnswer, related_name="real_answer")
```

Initially admin-interface is enough, to work with these questions. It should be visible on a "per question" basis, hence the "question" should show the answers it allows and the answers users can give:

admin.py:

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline): 
  model = Answer

class PossibleAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = PossibleAnswer   

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [PossibleAnswerInline, AnswerInline]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Everything works great, until I save the answers, which produces an IntegrityError. I believe this relates to dependencies between objects?

Second item I could not get around with: to limit choices for real_answer to actual options (that are related to the question), I defined the following in forms.py:

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Answer

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
    super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
    choices = self.instance.question.possible_answer.all()
    self.fields["real_answer"].choices = choices
```

and use it in admin.py as followed:

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline): 
  model = Answer
  form = AnswerForm
```

when I run this,  self.instance.question.possible_answer.all() *always* raises DoesNotExist

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Best,

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

When an `AnswerForm` is initialized, its instance attribute won't always have a question object related to it, so anytime you reference `self.instance.question` from the form, the `DoesNotExist` exception will be thrown if there isn't a question instance attached to the form's answer object yet.

Try this code instead in your form **init** method:

```
choices = []
if self.instance.pk
    questions = Question.objects.filter(answer=self.instance)
    if questions.exist():
        choices = questions.get().possibleanswer_set.all()
```

Comment: great approach and it almost works.

when django admin displays the form, is there a way to limit options, too? in already existing answers, it works, but not in the new line on bottom.

Comment: There should be, yes, please refer to Django's admin (and possibly forms) documentation for that.

Comment: Shouldn't that be in the AnswerForm, too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly building on @GonzaloDelgado's answer, but I don't feel his code is optimal. It's better to use a `try...except` block.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
...
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.instance.pk:
        try:
            self.fields['real_answer'].queryset = self.question.possibleanswer_set.all()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Comment: Not for something like that. The edit would (and should be) rejected for being a "radical change: This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost."

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't have thought refactoring my code (making it "optimal") would lose the meaning or intent of my answer.

Comment: beyond the initial issue, how is __init__(...) called here? when trying to instanciate AnswerForm in a view with   
   **answer = Answer(question=q, user=request.user)**
   **a = AnswerPublicForm(instance=answer)**
actually shows all answer options (just like the admin)

Comment: That's because there's a conditional on `self.instance.pk` having a value, which it won't until the `Answer` has been saved at least once.  Now that I think about it, that's actually probably not required, so try removing the `if self.instance.pk:` bit.

Comment: One last ditch effort, the actual `question` attribute might force the need to save in order to look itself up. You can try using `self.instance.question_id` to filter `PossibleAnswer` instead.